# Why does Lisp allow replacement of math operators in let?

Tags: clojure, scheme, lisp

I know in Scheme I can write this:

```
(let ((+ *)) (+ 2 3)) => 6
```

As well as this, in Clojure:

```
(let [+ *] (+ 2 3)) => 6
```

I know this can work, but it feels so weird.  I think in any language, the math operators are predefined.  C++ and Scala can do operator overloading, but this doesn't seem to be that.

Doesn't this cause confusion?  Why does Lisp allow this?

Comment: Note also that in a Lisp-2, binding a variable does not change the binding in the function namespace.

Comment: Note that in Scheme, the correct syntax is: `(let ((+ *)) (+ 2 3)) => 6`

Comment: In Lisp et ses derivees, `+`, `-`, etc are not operators - they're functions, and to misquote a certain cat: "A function does whatever we say it does, neither more nor less". Welcome to the looking glass. With great power comes great responsibility. Mind your head...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a general Lisp feature.

In Common Lisp the effects of binding a core language function is [*undefined*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abab.htm). This means the developer should not expect that it works in portable code. An implementation may also signal a warning or an error.

For example the [SBCL](http://sbcl.org) compiler will signal this error:

```
; caught ERROR:
;   Lock on package COMMON-LISP violated when
;   binding + as a local function while
;   in package COMMON-LISP-USER.
;   See also:
;     The SBCL Manual, Node "Package Locks"
;     The ANSI Standard, Section 11.1.2.1.2

;     (DEFUN FOO (X Y)
;       (FLET ((+ (X Y)
;                (* X Y)))
;         (+ X Y)))
```

We can have our own `+` in Common Lisp, but it then has to be in a different *package* (= symbol namespace):

```
(defpackage "MYLISP"
  (:use "CL")
  (:shadow CL:+))

(in-package "MYLISP")

(defun foo (a b)
  (flet ((+ (x y)
           (* x y)))
    (+ a b)))
```

Comment: Common Lisp has gone to great lengths to ensure one cannot redefine the language. I wonder how much code it takes the implementation to get this right. (CLISP does complain about globals, but not `flet`)

Comment: @Sylvester: no, the language standard says, that the consequences are undefined.

Comment: So an implementation isn't required to signal an error like most implementations does? It's amazing how many of them act the same when it happens.

Comment: @Sylwester: CLISP has "package locks", so I don't think it takes that much code in CLISP.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: This is from a Clojure point of view.

`+` is just another function.  You can pass it around and write `sum` with it, have partial application, read docs about it, ...:

```clj
user=> (apply + [1 2 3])
6
user=> (reduce + [1 2 3])
6
user=> (map (partial + 10) [1 2 3])
(11 12 13)
user=> `+
clojure.core/+
user=> (doc +)
-------------------------
clojure.core/+
([] [x] [x y] [x y & more])
  Returns the sum of nums. (+) returns 0. Does not auto-promote
  longs, will throw on overflow. See also: +'
```

So you can have many `+` in different namespaces.  The core one get's "use"-ed for you by default, but you can simply write your own.  You can write your own DSL:

```clj
user=> (defn + [s] (re-pattern (str s "+")))
WARNING: + already refers to: #'clojure.core/+ in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user/+
#'user/+
user=> (+ "\\d")
#"\d+"
user=> (re-find (+ "\\d") "666")
"666"
```

It's not special form, it's nothing different from any other function.  So with that established, why should it *not* be allowed to be overriden?

Answer (score 2):

In Scheme you are making a local binding, shadowing whatever is higher, With `let`. Since `+` and `*` are just variables that just happen to evaluate to procedures you are just giving old procedures other variable names.

```scm
(let ((+ *))
  +)
; ==> #<procedure:*> (non standard visualization of a procedure)
```

In Scheme there are **no reserved words**. If you look at other languages the list of reserved words are quite high. Thus in Scheme you can do this:

```scm
(define (test v)
  (define let 10)           ; from here you cannot use let in this scope
  (define define (+ let v)) ; from here you cannot use define to define stuff
  define) ; this is the variable, not the special form
;; here let and define goes out of scope and the special forms are OK again
(define define +) ; from here you cannot use top level define
(define 5 6) 
; ==> 11
```

THe really nice thing about this is that if you choose a name and the next version of the standard happens to use the same name for something similar, but not compatible, your code will not break. In other languages  I have worked with a new version might introduce conflicts.

**R6RS makes it even easier**

From R6RS we have libraries. That means that we have full control over what top level forms we get from the standard into our programs. You have several ways to do it:

```scm
#!r6rs
(import (rename (except (rnrs base) +) (* +)))

(+ 10 20) 
; ==> 200
```

This is also OK.

```scm
#!r6rs
(import (except (rnrs base) +))    
(define + *)

(+ 10 20) 
; ==> 200 guaranteed
```

And finally:

```scm
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)) ; imports both * and +   
(define + *)         ; defines + as an alias to *

(+ 10 20) 
; ==> 200 guaranteed
```

**Other languages does this too:**

JavaScript is perhaps the most obvious:

```scm
parseFloat = parseInt;
parseFloat("4.5") 
// ==> 4
```

But you cannot touch their operators. They are reserved because the language needs to do a lot of stuff for the operator precedence. Just like Scheme JS is nice language for duck typing.

Answer (score 2):

Mainstream Lisp dialects do not have reserved tokens for infix operations. There is no categorical difference between `+`, `expt`, `format` or `open-file`: they are all just symbols.

A Lisp proram which performs `(let ((+ 3)) ...)` is spiritually very similar to a C program which does something like `{ int sqrt = 42; ... }`.  There is a `sqrt` function in the standard C library, and since C has a single namespace (it's a Lisp-1), that `sqrt` is now shadowed.

What we can't do in C is `{ int + = 42; ...}` which is because `+` is an operator token. An identifier is called for, so there is a syntax error.  We also can't do `{ struct interface *if = get_interface(...); }` because `if` is a reserved keyword and not an identifier, even though it looks like one. Lisps tend not to have reserved keywords, but some dialects have certain symbols or categories of symbols that can't be bound as variables. In ANSI Common Lisp, we can't use `nil` or `t` as variables. (Specifically, those symbols `nil` and `t` that come from the `common-lisp` package).  This annoys some programmers, because they'd like a `t` variable for "time" or "type". Also, symbols from the keyword package, usually appearing with a leading colon, cannot be bound as variables.  The reason is that all these symbols are self-evaluating. `nil`, `t` and the keyword symbols evaluate to themselves, and so do not act as variables to denote another value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason we allow this in lisp is that all bindings are done with *lexical scope*, which is a concept that comes from *lambda calculus*.

lambda calculus is a simplified system for managing variable binding. In lambda calculus the rules for things like

```
(lambda (x) (lambda (y) y))
```

and

```
(lambda (x) (lambda (y) x))
```

and even

```
(lambda (x) (lambda (x) x))
```

are carefully specified.

In lisp LET can be thought of as syntactic sugar for a lambda expression, for example your expression `(let ([+ x]) (+ 2 3))` is equivalent to `((lambda (+) (+ 2 3)) x)` which according to lambda calculus simplifies down to `(x 2 3)`.

In summary, lisp is based on *uniformly* applying a very simple and clear model (called lambda calculus). If it seems strange at first, that's because most other programming languages don't have such consistency or base their variable binding on a mathematical model.

Comment: (when i say lisp in this post I actually mean 'scheme')

Answer (score 1):

It's not weird because in lisp there are no operators except functions and special forms like `let` or `if`, that can be builtin or created as macros. So here `+` is not an operator, but a function that is assigned to symbol `+` that is adding its arguments (in scheme and clojure you can say that it's just variable that hold function for adding numbers), the same `*` is not multiplication operator but asterisk symbol that is multiplying its arguments, so this is just convenient notation that it use `+` symbol it could be `add` or `sum` but `+` is shorter and similar as in other languages.

This is one of this mind bending concepts when you found it for the first time, like functions as arguments and return values of other functions.

If you use very basic Lisp and lambda calculus you don't even need numbers and `+` operators in base language. You can create numbers from functions and plus and minus functions using same trick and assign them to symbols `+` and `-` (see [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding))

Comment: I don't understand why I've got down vote, `+` is not an operator in lisp it's just function, this answer is extension of that. It was suppose to be a comment.

Comment: Well, the language is called Lisp, not LIPS. Actually the original Lisp from McCarthy is not really supporting lambda calculus semantics, it even did not support lexical closures. That took quite a bit time to figure out. The original Lisp from McCarthy had direct support for numeric operations and it would have been not practical to replace them with functions. The original addition operation for (float) numbers in Lisp 1 was named SUM. In many Lisp systems it would not be a good idea to globally redefine + with your own implementation...

Comment: @RainerJoswig thanks for the comment, after I've created lisp interpreter called lips I keep making typos when I write lisp.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I didn't want to say that it's practical to replace `+` with your own implementation only it's possible (only with scheme or Clojure) and that you don't need `+` at all to create one, you can get it from air (reference to original SICP videos and `cons`, `car` and `cdr` implementation).

Comment: 'only it's possible' -> not in general, because + then may crash Lisp or your program in interesting ways, because a global function might get called from all kinds of places (-> late binding)

Comment: @RainerJoswig it's the same as with `car`, `cdr` and `cons` from SICP videos (they were create from closures) it's not something you do normally in your code, but something you can to learn how it works. The same with church numerals you can test this to know that it works as exercise not something you do in real code.

Comment: Right, you can't replace the CAR function with your own - unless it is fully compatible with the original. Maybe even then it's not possible. Just as one can't replace the + function with your own. In a real practical Lisp. In a video on a white board it's possible though. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Scheme's philosophy is to impose minimal restriction such that to give maximal power to programmer.

A reason to allow such things is that in Scheme you can embed other languages and in other languages you want to use the `*` operator with different semantics.

For example, if you implement a language to represent regular expressions you want to give the `*` the semantics of the algebraic *kleene operator* and write programs like this one

> (* (+ "abc" "def") )

to represent a language that contain words like this one

```
empty
abc
abcabc
abcdef
def
defdef
defabc
....
```

Starting from the main language, untyped lambda calculus, it is possible to create a language in which you can redefine absolutely everything apart from the *lambda* symbol.  This is the model of computation scheme is build on.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does Lisp allow rebinding of math operators?

- for consistency and
- because it can be useful.

> Doesn't this cause confusion?

- No.

Most programming languages, following traditional algebraic notation, have special syntax for the elementary arithmetic functions of addition and subtraction and so on. Rules of priority and association make some function calls implicit. This syntax makes the expressions easier to read at the price of consistency.

LISPs tip the see-saw the other way, preferring consistency over legibility.

**Consistency**

In Clojure (the Lisp I know), the math operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, ... ) are nothing special.

- Their names are just ordinary symbols.
- They are `core` functions like any others.

So of course you can replace them.

**Usefulness**

Why would you want to override the core arithmetic operators? For example, [the `units2` library](https://github.com/mfey/units2) redefines them to accept dimensioned quantities as well as plain numbers.

---

Clojure algebra is harder to read.

- All operators are prefix.
- All operator applications are explicit - no priorities.

If you are determined to have infix operators with priorities, you can do it. [Incanter](http://incanter.org/) does so: [here](https://data-sorcery.org/2010/05/14/infix-math/) are some examples and [here](https://github.com/incanter/incanter/blob/master/modules/incanter-core/src/incanter/infix.clj) is the source code.